# python flask script killed by SIGKILL

Tags: python-2.7, flask

My code is working fine locally, but running into an error server side.

My code is trying to upload a file, but I checked whether the write permissions enabled or not and no problem with write permissions.

Here is the error:

```
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 159, in run_wsgi
    execute(app)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 146, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1506, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1339, in make_response
    return self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 711, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 55, in _run_wsgi_app
    return _run_wsgi_app(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 818, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: 'exceptions.ValueError' object is not callable
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL
error: Script restart attempt #12
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:5000/
```

My Code

```
@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    try :
        if request.method == 'POST':
                #print request.files
                uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file")
                #print uploaded_files
                uploads =os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))   
                zipf = zipfile.ZipFile('Python.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

                for f in uploaded_files :
                    f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
                    #print "File Name  "+secure_filename(f.filename)
                    processExcel(secure_filename(f.filename))
                    splited = secure_filename(f.filename).split(".")
                    dest_filename = splited[0]+"output"+".xlsx"
                    zipf.write(dest_filename)

                zipf.close()
                return render_template("uploader.html")
    except Exception as e :
        print "Exception in Process Excel"
        print e
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve]). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Meaning: you really cant just drop the stack trace here and assume that somebody will be able to help with that. Most of the libs in there are obviously your own code. Sorry, but without a [mcve], nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Big chances problem is on the WSGI-server side, please add information related to it (WSGI server app, configs, logs if present).

Comment: after deep research i found i need to install some pyexcel-xls,pyexcel-xlsx and pyexcel-xlsw packages.after pip install these packages server running fine